# Cannot run gradle from GIT Bash: fork: retry: No child processes

Tags: git, git-bash

I was able to run gradle from GIT Bash but with new Git bash 2.8.4 it gives:

```
0 [main] bash 7300 fork: child 8612 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
/bin/gradle: fork: retry: No child processes
```

Comment: I have seen this on my own machines running git "flow" from bash and windows command lines.  I haven't figured out the issue, but I am betting it is not "gradle" that is causing it.

Comment: It's not gradle that's causing it.  Git Bash does this.  I don't know why either.  I've tried an old version of Git for Windows, 2.6.1, and it does not have this problem.  But I would like to know how to get newer versions of Git for Windows to work correctly.

Comment: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/910